# how can save a string as it is in mysql database

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, utf-8

Im trying to save this string:

```
~`@#$%^&*()_+}{":?><,./;'[]=-|\
```

using a AJAX call in php. But in the database it saves as this:

```
~`@#$%^????
```

this is my AJAX call

```
function saveComment(timesheetId,activityId,date,comment,employeeId) {

    var r = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: commentlink,
        data: "timesheetId="+timesheetId+"&activityId="+activityId+"&date="+date+"&comment="+comment+"&employeeId="+employeeId,
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    return r;
}
```

Edit: Fixed display of strings and code.

Comment: what a ugly string to save lol

Comment: So ugly, SO couldn't handle the escaping properly!

Comment: This is JavaScript code. Where is PHP code?

Comment: Don't (!) to synchronous Ajax requests. They freeze the entire browser while they are running. There are better ways to handle the return value than this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to in javascript call [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on the string with the weird characters before you send it to the server.

EDIT: Tomalak pointed out a better method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put a variable 'text' in the data, you should run it through $.URLEncode(text) before doing so; as it is, the '&' character in the text introduces a new parameter.

Comment: `$.URLEncode()` is jQuery specific, make sure to mention this in your answer.

Comment: I felt it wasn't relevant given the question was obviously using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

jQuery supports an object as the data parameter in Ajax requests. This also does the URL encoding for you automatically:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: commentlink,
  data: {
    timesheetId: timesheetId, 
    activityId:  activityId, 
    date:        date, 
    comment:     comment, 
    employeeId:  employeeId
  },
  success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

Also - you should never use synchronous Ajax requests. Always work with callback functions.

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution it works fine.It stores in the database fine but i now have a problem when retrieving it again.IT SHOWS like ~`@#$%^&amp;*()_+}{&quot;:?&gt;&lt;,./;&#039;[]=-|\&quot;???????????

Comment: @tim: Since I have *no idea* how your server side code looks and what you intend to do with that data anyway, I can't answer this question. There is probably a call to `htmlspecialchars()` somewhere. In any case - here's a tip for the future: Make up your mind *before* asking a question. Ask it completely and state your intentions along with the code samples. No offense, but this Detective Columbo tactic of asking "just one more question" dosn't work too well on this site (at least not with me).